# Remove square brackets from wiki markup

Tags: php, preg-replace, wiki

I'm looking for the way to remove some markup from wikitext.

**Example:**

```
Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a [wiki=1c1ff8db21cf79377f9930e6e6ff8247]country[/wiki] in the southern portion of [wiki=5ffec2d87ab548202f8b549af380913a]North America[/wiki].
```

**Returned text should be:**

```
Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a country in the southern portion of North America.
```

**What we tried:**

```
preg_replace('/(\[.*?.\])/', '', $txt)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the pattern to replace the text **between** the open and close tags.

```
$markup = 'Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a [wiki=1c1ff8db21cf79377f9930e6e6ff8247]country[/wiki] in the southern portion of [wiki=5ffec2d87ab548202f8b549af380913a]North America[/wiki].';
$plain = preg_replace('/\[.*?\](.*?)\[\/.*?\]/', '$1', $markup);
echo $plain;
```

Output

```
Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a country in the southern portion of North America.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the wiki: you can use:

```
\[wiki=[^][]*](.+?)\[/wiki]
```

**Explanation**

- `\[wiki=` Match `[wiki=`
- `[^][]*` Optionally repeat matching any char except `[` or `]`
- `]` Match the closing square bracket
- `(.+?)` Capture group 1, match 1+ chars as least as possible
- `\[/wiki]` Match `[/wiki]`

In the replacement use group 1 like `$1`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3el7ZJ/1)

Example

```
$re = '`\[wiki=[^][]*](.+?)\[/wiki]`m';
$str = 'Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a [wiki=1c1ff8db21cf79377f9930e6e6ff8247]country[/wiki] in the southern portion of [wiki=5ffec2d87ab548202f8b549af380913a]North America[/wiki].
';

$result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);

echo $result;
```

Output

```
Mexico, officially the United Mexican States, is a country in the southern portion of North America.
```